# ImageMagick - Transparent background - Act like Photoshop's "Magic wand"

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, gimp

I'm trying to convert hundreds of images that

- Have an unknown subject centered in the image
- Have a white background

I've used [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org)'s `convert` utility in the following way

```
convert ORIGINAL.jpg -fuzz 2% -matte -transparent "#FFFFFF" TRANSPARENT.png
```

The problem is, some of my subjects are within the "white" scale, so, just like the [weatherman wearing a green tie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0CghAKgY4E), some of my subjects seem to be disitegrating.

Is there any way to solve this via ImageMagick? Are there any alternative solutions? *Scripting GIMP?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, GIMP has a magic wand tool that can be used to select **continuous** areas of the same color, and so it can avoid the "green tie syndrome". The problem is that it may introduce a problem if there is something like a human hair crossing the image (that will seperate some of the white areas). Another common problem, especially with pictures of people, is when they put their hand next to the body and between the hand and the body there is a small hole.

Basically, it is not too hard to create a GIMP script that opens in batch many images, uses the magic wand to select the pixel at some corner (or if desired, in several known fixed places, not just one) and then removes the selection.

If it's hard to find a white area at a fixed spot, it is possible to do a search inside - meaning that the script searches for a white pixel on the borders, and it goes inside gradually in a spiral untill it finds some white pixel. But this is very very unefficient in the basic scripting engine, so I hope you don't need this.

If any of the suggested options above is OK, tell me and I'll create a gimp script for it. It will be even better if you can post some samples images, but I'll try to help even without these.

Comment: These are example images; http://i.imgur.com/ZMzMD.png, http://i.imgur.com/EgO5V.png. Please note that I run GIMP under Windows and that the images are going to be resized down to about 200px before being displayed.

Comment: Actually, the chances one have a "real" white background are slim -- most likely one will have a background in various degress of light-low saturated colors, the separation of which form the picture can be tricky by using a single, uncalibrated parameter for magic wand, and even impossible if one tries to use the same parameter to a batch of different photos. But yes, trying a scripted approach in GIMP would be best in this scenario -- for example,t he script might apply a "stretch-contrast" filter prior to background selection that would make it easier.